# Having issues updating a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, dictionary

I have a simple function that receives two lists of dictionaries as parameters and is supposed to compare if the values in list A is in list B, then update list A and return the updated list A.

I have two issues with my function, firstly, it is not updating all the dictionaries in List A, it is just updating two, instead of three.
The user2 data, has three dict not two.
Secondly, I want to return a list of dictionaries, not multiple dictionaries as it is returning now.

This my function:

```
    from itertools import zip_longest

    def test(user, model):
        for d1, d2 in list(zip_longest(user, model, 
                                       fillvalue={
            "asset": "No Fund",
            "amount": 0
        }
                                      )):
            model_assets = d2["assets"]
            user_assets = d1["asset"]
            if any(user_assets in s for s in model_assets):
                    d1.update({"rating": d2["rating"]})
                    print(d1)

    test(user2, inv_class)
    output ---> 
    {'asset': 'Money Market Fund', 'amount': 100000, 'rating': 'Low-2'}
    {'asset': 'Easy Will', 'amount': 40000, 'rating': 'Moderate'}
```

The data:

```
inv_class = [
    {
  "rating": "Low-1",
  "score": "2-3",
  "type": "Capital Preservation",
  "assets": [
      "Money Market Fund",
      "Treasury Bills",
      "Easy Will",
      "Education Trust"
  ]
},
    {
  "rating": "Low-2",
  "score": "4-5",
  "type": "Income",
  "assets": [
      "Money Market Fund",
      "FGN Retail Savings/FGN Corporate Bonds",
      "Easy Will",
      "Education Trust"
  ]
},
    {
  "rating": "Moderate",
  "score": "6-7",
  "type": "Income & Growth",
  "assets": [
      "Euro-bond Fund",
      "Fixed Income Fund",
      "Ethical Fund",
      "Easy Will",
      "Education Trust"
  ]
},
     {
  "rating": "High",
  "score": "8",
  "type": "Growth",
  "assets": [
      "Discovery Fund",
      "Ethical Fund",
      "Local Stocks",
      "Foreign Stocks",
      "Easy Will",
      "Education Trust"
  ]
},
    {
  "rating": "Very High",
  "score": "9",
  "type": "Aggressive Growth",
  "assets": [
      "Aggressive Growth Fund",
      "Local Stocks",
      "Foreign Stocks",
      "Easy Will",
      "Education Trust"
  ]
}
]
```

user data:

```
user2 = [
        {
            "asset": "Fixed Income Fund",
            "amount": 150000
        },
           {
            "asset": "Money Market Fund",
            "amount": 100000
        },
           {
            "asset": "Easy Will",
            "amount": 40000
        }
    ]
```

Updated function:

```
def test3(user, model):
    result = []
    for u in user:
        y = u["asset"]
        for items in model:
            ind = items["assets"]
            for i in ind:
                if i in y:
                    u["rating"] = items["rating"]
        result.append(u)
    return result
```

Output:

```
test3(user1, inv_class)

[{'asset': 'Discovery Fund', 'amount': 100000, 'rating': 'High'},
 {'asset': 'Ethical Fund', 'amount': 200000, 'rating': 'High'},
 {'asset': 'Foreign Stocks', 'amount': 350000, 'rating': 'Very High'},
 {'asset': 'Local Stocks', 'amount': 550000, 'rating': 'Very High'}]
```

Please is this code efficient?

Please any assistance or guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Since you're zipping the two lists, you're only comparing the corresponding elements in the two lists, not comparing with every element in the other list.

Comment: is `any(user_assets in s for s in model_assets)` check necessary because this does a substring check among the assets present? I think this can be reduced to `user_assets in model_assets`.

Comment: **I want to return a list of dictionaries, not multiple dictionaries as it is returning now** You're not returning anything now. You're just printing in the loop.

Comment: `d1.update({"rating": d2["rating"]})` can be reduced to `d1["rating"] = d2["rating"]`.

Comment: I've updated my question with an updated function. please assist

Comment: Yes. I just did. Updated the function and output